# Using an Enum as a flag in a class, Python

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.4

I would like to use an enum to represent an internal state of a class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from enum import Enum


class testClass:
    class Color(Enum):
        red = 1
        blue = 2
        green = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def setValue(self, Color):
        self.value = Color
```

this is what I thought could be a possible implementation. The two annoying things that I see are:

1. to set `value` I have to do :

   `q = testClass()`

   `q.setValue(q.Color.red)`

   and I find the `q.Color.red` someway umpleasant, I'd rather have something like:`Color.red` or just `red`. Maybe the only way to have that is to use some string comparison, but it is exactly what I am trying to avoid using enum.
2. I get an extra method that is `q.Color.mro` that seems like an internal method of the enum class. What is this for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alternative #1: You can have the `Enum` class do the string lookup for you:

```
    def setValue(self, color):
        self.value = self.Color[color]
```

Usage:

```
q = testClass()
q.setValue('red')
```

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes

---

Alternative #2: If there are no conflicts, you can promote the Enum's members to the parent class:

```
class testClass:
    class Color(Enum):
        red = 1
        blue = 2
        green = 3
    red = Color.red
    blue = Color.blue
    green = Color.green

    def setValue(self, color):
        self.value = color
```

Usage:

```
q = testClass()
q.setValue(q.red)
```

Comment: The `red`/`blue`/`green` assignments can be replaced with `locals().update(Color.__members__)`

Answer (score 1):

If your Class Color wont be conflicting with anything else in your application, you can move Color class out of testClass.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    red = 1 
    blue = 2 
    green = 3 


class testClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0 

    def setValue(self, Color):
        self.value = Color
```

Then you will be able to use

```
q = testClass()
q.setValue(Color.b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, just that the class testClass is defined in another file from the main one. I import testClass with `from testClassfile import testClass` . If I follow your advice I will have to add also `from testClassfile import Color`. 
I know that maybe I'm too picky but I am trying to find an "elegant" way...

Comment: Well if you want to import is as part of testClass you will have to stick with referencing it as testClass.Color
EDIT: For extra style points you can import both classes (if separate) in one line by:
from testClassfile import testClass, Color